# Running bridged-networking vmware player on a Linux machine with 2 interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, virtualization, vmware-player, arch-linux

I have got a laptop running Arch Linux with 2 interfaces: wireless (`wlan0`) and ethernet (`eth0`). I use `wlan0` to access internet (static IP, networking is configured using netcfg), and I connect a second PC to the `eth0`.

Now, whenever I start vmware player (v. 4.0.4), it chooses `wlan0` to connect its bridged virtual NIC to, but I need it to connect to `eth0` (I want my guest machine to be able to talk to the second physical PC on `eth0`). So, I disable the `wlan0` interface (`netcfg -d wireless`) and restart vmware. Now, it connects to `eth0`, and everything works fine; I can ping the host PC from the virtual one, and I can ping the virtual PC from the second physical PC connected to `eth0`. Then, if I try to reenable the wlan0 interface (`netcfg -u wireless`), all of the connectivity between the host and the guest (and between the second physical PC and the guest) gets lost, until I disable `wlan0` again. Can someone please give me a hint on what's going on?

Comment: http://support.tranzeo.com/knowledgebase/users/kb.php?id=10053 might help you out..

Comment: They recommend basically what I am already doing.. Whenever I reenable the wireless interface, all of the communications between the guest and the host on the wired interface fail.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use VM player. The networking capabilities are limited. The full version will let you choose the desired physical interface so you don't have to "disable interface" to trick vmware.

Or if you are looking for a free one, use virtualbox.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm stuck with VMWare Player for now.